# How to fix after the on blur event the textbox shows again?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, onblur

After I type the input the textbox shows again in and I don't know how to fix. Here's the screen shot of the output:

[image]

Is shows again after the on blur

Here's my code, and I don't know how to fix this. though my function works well

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Amateur</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            function check_email() {
                var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"index.php",
                    data: "email="+email,
                    success:function(msg) {
                        $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="txtEmail">E-mail:</label>
            <input id="txtEmail" name="email" type="email" onblur="return check_email()">
        <label id="chkEmail" for="txtEmail"></label>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['email']))
        {
            $user='root';

            $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=class;charset=utf8',$user);

            $email=$_POST['email'];

            $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT user_email from tbl_users WHERE user_email=:email LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));

            if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
                echo 'E-mail already use.';
            }
            else {
                echo 'E-mail not use.';
            }   
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Html, js, php all in one file. Make sure the person who will support this code after you don't know where you live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this. The issue is you POST the data to the same page your are in and you get the whole code as the response for you AJAX request. So if you exit the execution on POST you will only get the relevant message.

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_POST['email']))
        {
            $user='root';

            $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=class;charset=utf8',$user);

            $email=$_POST['email'];

            $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT user_email from tbl_users WHERE user_email=:email LIMIT 1');
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));

            if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
                echo 'E-mail already use.';
            }
            else {
                echo 'E-mail not use.';
            } 
            exit;  
        }
        ?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Amateur</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            function check_email() {
                var email=$("#txtEmail").val();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"index.php",
                   data: { 
            'email': email
                },
                    success:function(msg) {
                        $("#chkEmail").html(msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="txtEmail">E-mail:</label>
            <input id="txtEmail" name="email" type="email" onblur="return check_email()">
        <label id="chkEmail" for="txtEmail"></label>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wait there is a problem in your POST

Comment: yes , index.php .. should I really need to put the php script outside the html?

Comment: what's wrong in my POST? I works sir when I follow your code I am just wondering why outside the html? Thank you

Comment: It's better if you can use something like MVC architecture or your own code division. One day you will realize how easy to maintain your code or bug fixes.

Comment: Yes sir, I'll try that I am still a starter in PHP and Jquery It's just been a week since I started thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

in `check_email` function before `return false` add

```
$("#txtEmail").hide();
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: No sir, the output should just one line, the error should show inline with the try@try.com